# Unix sort when sequence resets

Tags: sort

I have below list of files in a folder. Every file name has date and time (`yyyymmdd_hhmm`) in it. The last 3 characters are the sequence number which resets at `999` and after this max sequence, the sequence will again start from `001`.

```
node55_20200420_1755_995
node55_20200420_1756_998
node55_20200420_1755_996
node55_20200420_1757_999
node55_20200420_1756_997
node55_20200420_1757_001
node55_20200420_1758_002
node55_20200420_1758_003
```

When I use command

```
ls node* | sort
```

I get below get output. I want sequence `001` after the `999`. The command works fine except when sequence reset appears. Any idea how to handle it ?

**Actual output**

```
node55_20200420_1755_995
node55_20200420_1755_996
node55_20200420_1756_997
node55_20200420_1756_998
node55_20200420_1757_001
node55_20200420_1757_999
node55_20200420_1758_002
node55_20200420_1758_003
```

**Desired output**

```
node55_20200420_1755_995
node55_20200420_1755_996
node55_20200420_1756_997
node55_20200420_1756_998
node55_20200420_1757_999
node55_20200420_1757_001
node55_20200420_1758_002
node55_20200420_1758_003
```

Comment: How would you handle the theoretical case of 999 files labelled `20200420_1757_001` to `20200420_1757_999` then, if `20200420_1757_999` should sort _before_ `20200420_1757_001`?  It would be better to sort according to modification timestamp, _if the resolution of that was good enough_, maybe something like `ls -tr`? What shell are you using?

Comment: Also, are you wanting to _do_ something to these names, or just list them?

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, thanks. If there are 999 files with same date and time stamp, than 999 should be at the end and 001 should be at start.  ls -tr not working for cases like, if 997 reaches the folder before 996.

Comment: I am using bash, I just want to list them. Actually I use this sorted list in another application where I find the missing sequences.

Comment: I don't understand your logic here. Why would `1757_999` be sorted before `1757_001`?  And if 999 should be before 001, then shouldn't 003 also be before 002?

Comment: @terdon it's a sequence number truncated to three digits

Comment: @terdon since sequence resets after 999 and again starts from 001. So I want 999 before 001.

Comment: Ah, OK, I get it. Can the actual timestamps of the files help?

Comment: @terdon  It will not help, because its possible that 997 reaches the folder before 996.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily sort some of your output one way but make an exception another way.

If only `999` and `000` were the sequences in a single given minute you could try to split the filename into fields and sort the final field (your sequence counter) in descending order. But that couldn't work because your example shows `995` and `996` also in the same minute (`20200420_1755`) and the same sorting criterion would apply to those too (i.e. you'd get `996` followed by `995`).

So, in order to handle this specific situation we use some `awk`. The code extends your three digit sequence number back into a proper counting value, sorts by that, and then strips it back off again

```
ls node* |
    sort |                                                  # First pass attempt
    awk -F_ '
        BEGIN { OFS = FS }                                  # Delimiter always "_"
        (oseq % 1000) == 999 { thousands++ }                # After previous 999 add 1000
        { seq = $NF + (thousands * 1000) }                  # Convert sequence into value
        seq < oseq && (seq % 1000) < 500 { seq += 1000 }    # Special case
        { $5 = seq; oseq = seq; print }                     # Append counter, output result
    ' |
    sort -t_ -n -k5,6 |                                     # Sort by counter
    cut -d_ -f1-4                                           # Strip it off
```

Result using your example dataset

```
node55_20200420_1755_995
node55_20200420_1755_996
node55_20200420_1756_997
node55_20200420_1756_998
node55_20200420_1757_999
node55_20200420_1757_001
node55_20200420_1758_002
node55_20200420_1758_003
```

This code is not bulletproof. If you really want to generate anywhere more than 100 instances in a single minute then you shouldn't be using just a three digit sequence number.

Comment: Thanks, though your code is bit advanced for me but its working on my test data set. This is sure that in a single minute sequences will be less than 10. To make my question simple, I used only 3 digits sequences. Actually there are 5 digits in the sequence i.e. 99999 is max sequence. I face problem only where 99999 and 00001 come in same minute.

Comment: Semantically, the code is wrong for five-digit sequences. You showed three digits so I named the variable that manages the counting `thousands`. You could usefully rename it `blocks` or `groups` or even `hundredthousands`. If the code works for you please remember to accept it with the tickmark.